# How can I return a msg box if my AdvancedFilter function does not find any matching results?

Tags: excel

```
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B3:H3")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You have not specified any criteria!"
Else
    Sheets("STOCK_DB").Range("B1:H2000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("B2:H3"), CopyToRange:=Range("B4:H2000"), Unique:= _
    False

    Sheets("STOCK SEARCH").Range("B4").EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

If the AdvancedFilter does not find any matching results to my search criteria in range B3:H3, I need a msg box to be displayed. I can't figure this one out!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the specialcells property to count the number of visible cells:

```
    If Sheets("STOCK_DB").Range("B1:H2000").Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1 = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No results"
    End If
```

Further info here: [Row count on the Filtered data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285897/row-count-on-the-filtered-data)