# Copying result rows from filtered sheet ignoring blank or empty

Tags: vba, excel

everyone. I am newie on this, but i need this so i am asking for your help.
I am building a macro to copy filtered data from several books to a consolitation one. The following code run fine until one filtered worksheet has no result rows, then it copy a range of empty cells, in that moment a receive an error 1004 that a can't solve. This is my code (result of several adaptation of code to my need):

```
Sub MergeDataFromWorkbooks()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook
    
    Set wbk1 = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    
    Path = "D:\Reportes\Prueba\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do While Len(Filename) > 0
    
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
        
        wbk.Activate
        
        If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        End If
        
        With ActiveSheet
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            .Range("B6:BB6").AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="*Nacional*"
        End With
                
        Range("B7").Select
        Range(Selection, "BA7").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.Copy
        
        Windows("Merged.xlsm").Activate
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        Dim lr As Double
        
        lr = wbk1.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        'Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Sheets("Hoja1").Select
        Cells(lr + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True
                        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        wbk.Close True
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
    MsgBox "All the files are copied and pasted in Merged."
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to check whether there are any filtered cells, so wrap copy/paste statements inside some `If - Then` as follows:

```
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("B6:BB6").AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="*Nacional*"
    End With

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns(2))) > 1 Then
        Range("B7").Select
        Range(Selection, "BA7").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.copy
        Windows("Merged.xlsm").Activate

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Dim lr As Double

        lr = wbk1.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).row
        'Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Sheets("Hoja1").Select
        Cells(lr + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    wbk.Close True
    Filename = Dir
```

Comment: BTW you have to get rid of all that `Select`/`Activate`/`Selection`/`ActiveXXX` and use fully qualified range references. You may see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: There are a lot of responses for counting rows of data for the question below, which could be useful for the if statement.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285897/row-count-on-the-filtered-data/34689072#34689072

Comment: This work for me!! Now i will try to follow your suggestions to minify the use of Select/Activate/Selection/ActiveXXX, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Check for visible values in the filtered range before copying.

```
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    with .Range("B6:BB6")
        .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="*Nacional*"
        with .resize(.rows.count-1, .columns.count).offset(1, 0)
            if cbool(application.subtotal(103, .cells)) then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy
            end if
        end with
    end with
End With
```

It's probably better to work out the destination beforehand and use the Destination parameter of the copy operation.

Comment: `.resize(.rows.count-1, .columns.count).offset(1, 0)` errors out since it's being applied to a single row range (`.Range("B6:BB6")`.