# Excel VBA filtering ignored

Tags: vba, excel

I was running some scenarios with my Excel 2016 VBA code and came to a problem which I can't seem to solve. So, the code below does this:

> 1. remove any existing filters on worksheet "Data"
> 2. apply new filters for the table on sheet "Data" so that
>      column "Location" would be filtered based on cell "G2" value (i.e. "South") + column "Quantity" would contain **only non-blanks**
> 3. select now filtered data range + Copy selection (entire potential range highlighted on the screenshot - i.e E5:F12)
> 4. Activate worksheet "Transit" and go to first empty cell in
>      highlighted range (A4:A10)
> 5. Perform Paste-values + de-activate filtering on the
>      previous sheet

It works, however with one crucial exception (should it matter, I'm launching the code from  worksheet `Transit`)

**In a scenario when there's nothing to copy, it copies everything (i.e. the entire `"Data_range"`)**. Based on screenshot below when location "South" is filtered, there are no rows with non-blank "Quantity". In a scenario like that, instead of copy-pasting nothing, it does the opposite and copy-pastes the entire range with no filtering.

I can't manually even perform such a procedure - is there a way to halt the code,  in case no filtering matches are found? Any other way to avoid such an excessive pasting?

```
Sub Copy()

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Data").ShowAllData

    With Sheets("Data")
    .Range("Items").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=.Range("G2").Value
    .Range("Items").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"    

    Application.Goto Reference:="Data_range"
    Selection.Copy

    Worksheets("Transit").Activate

    For Each cell In Range("First_empty_row").Cells
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
    Next cell

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    .Range("Items").AutoFilter Field:=2
    .Range("Items").AutoFilter Field:=5

End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You could check out this answer on counting the number of visible rows in a filtered list object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34689072/9259306 Change it to a function to return the count (might need to edit it to ensure it returns `0` when empty) then just compare the count to `>0`.

Comment: Thanks - I must admit the answer there ended up being too complicated for me to implement, however it induced me to look for a solution in a different manner and found a thing working for me here (posted by user ashu1990): https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/136803-stop-copy-paste-if-the-filtered-range-has-no-data