# IF statement when cell is not empty

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, count, visible

Could you please help me clear this code?

I'm trying to filter out certain dates, and if no cells are visible then don't execute the code.

For some reason I cannot get the `IF` working properly.

```
Dim EndDate1, StartDate1 As Long
Dim todayDate1 As Long

Sheets("Macro").Select
todayDate1 = Sheets("Macro").Cells(2, 2)

Sheets("FTC").Select
StartDate1 = DateSerial(Year(todayDate1),Month(todayDate1),Day(todayDate1) + 14)
EndDate1 = DateSerial(Year(todayDate1), Month(todayDate1), Day(todayDate1) + 21)

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AP$1000").AutoFilter Field:=24, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & EndDate1
Range("A2:A1000").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

If Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Nope"
End If
MsgBox "Yay"
```

Comment: You can use AutoFilter's range property to return the entire range that AutoFilter uses... try comparing `AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1` after your AutoFilter declaration

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!).  Also, it would be helpful if you [edit] your question to provide some sample data, as well as example(s) of your desired outcome. See how to create a **[mcve]** and also check out [ask]. Other great tips from the site's top user **[here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**.

Comment: @maja Which dates are you trying to filter?

Comment: @Maja - What are you trying to do with `If Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count>1`?

Comment: just to give you context it is only part of the code.
todayDate is drawn from  cell in the excel..
my idea was to filter out selection of dates but if no dates fit this requirements 14-21 then what ever code is in if will be ignored and code will continue with something else. Basically like check because the code was giving me error if there was nothing to filter. so i was counting the first column and if there were no visible cells it would continue with different result

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of minor issues with your code, but your question was well-written and the effort you made is on the right track (and we all have to start somewhere) so kudos on that!

---

**I *think* this is what you're trying to do:**

```
Sub FilterDemo()

    Const filterField = 24
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Macro")
    Dim filterRange As Range: Set filterRange = ws.Range("A:AP")
    Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date, visibleRows As Long

    'assuming you want to use "today's date"? (returned by function [Date])
    dtStart = Date + 14
    dtEnd = Date + 21

    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1 'clear existing filter

    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=filterField, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & Format(dtStart, "yyyy-MM-dd"), _
        Criteria2:="<=" & Format(dtEnd, "yyyy-MM-dd")

    visibleRows=ws.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
            .Cells.Count - 1

    If visibleRows = 0 Then
        filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1  'remove filter
        MsgBox "No data found between " & dtStart & " and " & dtEnd & ".", _
            vbExclamation, "No Data Found"
    Else
        MsgBox visibleRows &" items between" & dtStart &" and "& dtEnd & ".", _
            vbInformation, "Data found!"
    End If

End Sub
```

---

## *Notes:*

- Great that you [declared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-variables) your variables - but better to declare dates as [data type `Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary). Excel does store dates internally as numbers (although not integers) but it's still best to declare the variables as `Date` and let Excel figure out the rest.

  Since we're using the proper `Date` date type, we can simply add days to each other (instead of using [`DateSerial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dateserial-function)). ([More about dates](https://support.microsoft.com/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel).)
- You declared `StartDate1 As Long` but not `EndDate1`: you *can* declare multiple variables on one line, but if any don't have a type specified then they default to [`Variant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/variant-data-type).
- I assume cell `B2` just holds the *current* date? — if so, instead use the VBA [the `Date` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/date-function).
- When passing dates as a parameter, it's a good idea to [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) them in a way we know [AutoFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) will understand., which also converts to  [String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary).

  It would *probably* also work fine like `Criteria1:=">=" & dtStart, Criteria2:="<=" & dtEnd` but the *right way* to do it is to convert to a string, since that's what [AutoFilters' criteria](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) areexpecting.
- [`Select` statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-select-method-excel) should be avoided if possible (and should be "tidied" when [using code from a recorded a macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros)).  For example, *this*:

  ```
  Range("A2:A1000").Select
  Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
  If Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
  ```

  ...becomes *this*:

  ```
  If Range("A2:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
  ```

  Important related reading: [**How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/8112776)
- By specifying range `A1:AP1000`, the [`Count` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-count-property-excel) will count *all* the rows up to 1000, only deducting the number of rows hidden by the filter.

  Instead of specifying an arbitrary set of rows, I refer to *entire columns*.  AutoFilter "creates" a range of the cells it's using, and we can refer to like this expression:  (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17287558/8112776))

  ```
  ws.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
  ```

---

When trying to figure out a long expression like this, it's helpful to read it right-to-left (or, for illustrative purposes, *upside-down!*)

[image: upside down example]

---

- Next, either your [operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/comparison-operators) or mine are **incorrect** in the AutoFilter criteria, depending on whether the values in your dates column *have **times** attached*.

  - Your code sample uses `>=StartDate and <EndDate`

    > Yours **excludes** values of **midnight on the `EndDate`**. But if there are *no* times attached then yours is excluding "the whole day" of the `EndDate`.  If there are times attached, then yours includes up to `11:59:59pm` on the day before the `EndDate`.
  - My code example uses `>=StartDate and <=EndDate`.

    > Mine **includes** values of **midnight on the `EndDate`**, and if there are no times attached to the data, the whole of `EndDate` is included.  Yours is the correct way for use when querying time multiple date ranges, to prevent overlaps. ([More about date/times](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T012742_Determining_If_a_Date_is_between_Other_Dates.html).)
- Finally (mainly cosmetic), note that your `MsgBox "Yay"` will appear regardless of whether the `MsgBox "Nope"` does or doesn't appear.

  This is avoided with `Exit Sub` (to end the procedure immediately), **or** by using an `Else` with your `If` statement. ([More about `If..Then..Else`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/using-ifthenelse-statements).)

Hopefully this makes sense... Good luck!

Comment: Sir...This is awesome.. i would need explenation like this for all of my coding.. i can make stuff happen but i have only gener idea of whats happening in it. Thank you a lot. The issue has been solved by using Range("A2:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1