# How to get rid of error if a filtered option does not exist for all criteria?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to write a code that it filters out by production day.
It then filters for the different lines (field 3) (Line A/B, Line C, etc)
and it then takes the item numbers for those and pastes it into another sheet.

However, now when I change the day criteria to another day - for example day 6...
not all the lines which existed in Day 1 exist.
So if I replace field 1, criteria one with 6 instead of 1, it messes up the sheet because Line A/B does not exist for Day 6.

how can i tweak this code so that even if that specific line filter does not exist for a certain day - it ignores or doesn't mess up the rest of the sheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Range("D7:O7").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$D$7:$O$52").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "1,120.67", "1,200.00", "10,472.00", "121.00", "185.00", "190.50", "24.00", "241.50", _
    "30.00", "436.00", "450.00", "465.00", "500.00", "525.00", "54.00", "60.00", "630.00", _
    "71.00", "756.00", "893.00", "90.00", "984.50", "991.00"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
ActiveSheet.Range("$D$7:$O$52").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
ActiveSheet.Range("$D$7:$O$52").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="A/B"
Range("E8:E52").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Production Schedule - Daily").Select
Range("I12").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("July Production for Open Orders").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$D$7:$O$52").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=B/C", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Line B"
Range("E8:E52").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Production Schedule - Daily").Select
Range("U12").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("July Production for Open Orders").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$D$7:$O$52").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Line C"
Range("E8:E52").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Production Schedule - Daily").Select
Range("AG12").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("July Production for Open Orders").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$D$7:$O$52").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Line O"
Range("E8:E52").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Production Schedule - Daily").Select
Range("AS12").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("July Production for Open Orders").Select
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Sheets("Production Schedule - Daily").Select
Range("E1").Select
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285897/row-count-on-the-filtered-data) shows one way to count how many results there are, so that you could use an `If` statement to check whether any item numbers exist to copy

Comment: What do you mean by "it messes up the sheet" - what happens exactly which you don't want?

Comment: @TimWilliams  It places  different items in all random parts of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code by using some variables to refer to the sheets and ranges you're using, and by extracting the "copy and paste visible cells only" steps to a separate Sub which you can call from your main code.  Use some error handling to take care of cases where all rows are filtered and there are no visible cells to copy.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim rngTable As Range, rngHdrs As Range, rngCopy As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngVis As Range, wsPS As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'source sheet
    Set wsPS = ws.Parent.Worksheets("Production Schedule - Daily")
    
    Set rngTable = ws.Range("D7:O52")                    'whole table
    Set rngHdrs = rngTable.Rows(1)                       'headers
    Set rngCopy = rngTable.Columns(2).Offset(1, 0). _
                  Resize(rngTable.Rows.Count - 1)        'Col E, data only
    
    rngHdrs.AutoFilter
    rngTable.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "1,120.67", "1,200.00", "10,472.00", "121.00", "185.00", "190.50", "24.00", "241.50", _
        "30.00", "436.00", "450.00", "465.00", "500.00", "525.00", "54.00", "60.00", "630.00", _
        "71.00", "756.00", "893.00", "90.00", "984.50", "991.00"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues
    
    rngTable.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
    
    rngTable.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="A/B"
    CopyVisible rngCopy, wsPS.Range("I12")
    
    rngTable.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=B/C", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Line B"
    CopyVisible rngCopy, wsPS.Range("U12")
    
    rngTable.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Line C"
    CopyVisible rngCopy, wsPS.Range("U12")
    
    rngTable.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Line O"
    CopyVisible rngCopy, wsPS.Range("AS12")
    
    ws.ShowAllData
    wsPS.Select
    wsPS.Range("E1").Select
    
End Sub

'copy all visible cells from `rngFrom` and paste as values to `rngTo`
'  Return False if no visible cells were found
Sub CopyVisible(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range)
    Dim vis As Range
    On Error Resume Next   'ignore error if no cells found
    Set vis = rngFrom.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0        'stop ignoring errors
    If Not vis Is Nothing Then
        vis.Copy
        rngTo.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
End Sub
```